# Porting a Visual C++ project to C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, open-source, porting

I got my hands on some well documented C++ code that's about 1KLOC. It would take me a significant amount of time to port this line by line and debug the results, so I'm wondering if there are tools or ways to do it faster, and I have questions in case I have to do it fully manually.

Specific questions:

- Does C# also support overriding operators like `*` and `+`?
- What to do with the C++ memory management code like alloc() and free()?
- How to identify functions used from `<stdio.h>`, `<conio.h>` and `<math.h>`?
- How to find replacements to such system functions?
- Does C# have any special/open source libraries that provide such functions?

No graphics libraries have been used, its purely command line based.

Comment: You actually use malloc and free in C++? I pity you.

Comment: @DeadMG, whoa... you really know the art of posting constructive comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this tool and see if that works out for you.  There is a demo where you translate up to a 100 lines of code at a time:

http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CPlusPlus_to_CSharp_Converter_Details.html

Try it out and let us know.  But it would prolly be more beneficial to port this yourself in c# so you can get a handle of the features that c# comes with.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do it manually, and 1KLOC isn't much.
However, you *will* need to learn C#.

To answer your questions:

- Yes
- Depending on what you're doing, probably `List<T>`
- I don't know what you're asking
- Look in the .Net Framework class library on MSDN
- Yes

Answer (score 1):

1 - C# also support operator overloading see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(VS.71).aspx (it looks very much to c++ operator overriding)

2 - C# is garbage collected so you only need "new" instead of alloc. free is done by the garbage collector

3 - I have no idea , but when porting code you would have to find in standard c# library the equivalents

4 - In MSDN there is a lot of information.

5 - ( http://code2code.net/ ) ??? but better to do it at hand

---

More information on coding standards : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx
ie naming: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72.aspx

Comment: this was made community wiki, people that know more than me would be able to contribute